# Upgraded to 5.4 but "php -v" still returns older version

Tags: php, macos

I'm on OSX Lion 10.7.5. As advised at [How do I upgrade PHP in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526085/how-do-i-upgrade-php-in-mac-os-x?s=fdcf34c5-b2d0-4b37-8d92-d8317880189c), I used:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4
```

Everything appeared to go well, no errors, I'm on a 64bit system, etc., but when I run "php -v" I still see the same version I had before (5.3.15). On a scale of 1-10 I'm probably a 2 when it comes to installing stuff via the command line, so, please factor that into any responses.

UPDATE: I took a closer look at the Terminal output after running `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4` and I noticed the following:

```
Installing package tools-memcached into root /
./pkg/pre-install
pkg/pre-install
Skipping existing directory 
Skipping existing directory usr/
Skipping existing directory usr/local/
```

...then at the end of the installation:

```
Create symlink /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
Removed /usr/lib from DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in /usr/sbin/envvars
Restarting Apache
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name
```

Can anybody elaborate on precisely what that means? As explained in the comments, it seems I've got the files installed, but, I'm having trouble resolving what appears to be a $PATH issue.

Comment: The old version of PHP is being found first in your `$PATH`.  To see which one you are calling from the CLI, do `which php`.  That will probably return some PHP 5.3 version.

Comment: @soulseekah: restarting didn't help, but thanks!

Comment: Then your old php (`which php`) path is different from the install path of this `install.sh` script which is `/usr/local/`, you have to `ln -s` or copy the old binary over to your `which php` path.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: when I run "which php" I get "/usr/bin/php" and when I run "/usr/bin/php -v" you are correct, it returns the old version. The php-osx.liip.ch page says "The php.ini is located in /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini," does that mean I have to add "/usr/local/php5/lib/" to the $PATH variable?

Comment: @CL75 The new one's executable path is probably /usr/loca/bin/php.  Find where the executable is, then add that to your `$PATH`.  However, that doesn't mean that Apache will find the right one either.  I can't necessarily help with that because I don't have a Mac handy.

Comment: In /usr/bin/ it seems there are only two php-related executable files, "php" and "php-config" neither of which were created today. How do I find out where the executable resides for the new installation? There are two PHP installations in /usr/local/, the one installed today is simply "php5". I'm not sure if this is right, but I tried these changes:

Old: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:

New: PATH=/usr/local/php5:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

…but it still lists the old version.

Comment: I also tried adding "/usr/local/php5/bin:" to $PATH because it seems there is php exe file in "php5/bin" but it still returns the old version.

Comment: Just to confirm, "/usr/local/php5/bin/php -v" returns "PHP 5.4.7", so it seems I've located the new install, but for some reason it still returns "5.3.15" when running "which php", even after adding /usr/local/php5/bin: to $PATH variable. Does that seem like the correct addition for the $PATH variable? Like I said, I'm pretty new to installing things via CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a sym link to the path of your new php install like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php php
```

Comment: What if it returns `ln: php: File exists`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache first disable current php module

> sudo a2dismod php5
>   sudo a2dismod php5.6

then enable

> sudo a2enmod php7.0

and restart apache

> sudo service apache2 restart