# can not enable openssl in php.ini

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php

I have the normal php build that comes with OSX (5.3.27) and the one that I downloaded with homebrew. ( 5.5.0 ) now I started to work with composer and want to install [laravel](http://laravel.com/) (PHP framework) but when I run the code to create a project I get the following error

You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

Well the issue is that I think it looks to the native php build on my computer and not in the one from homebrew ( tho I have removed the ; from both php.ini files. where stands extension=openssl.dll but nothing works) ( I use a mac with mountain lion ) and I know that openssl.dll must be a windows library since DLL is for windows and SO for unix based systems.. So how can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you execute `openssl version` by command line?

Comment: then I get OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: I would start by uninstalling the native one installed by your OS, and then make sure you're downloading the correct version from http://www.php.net/downloads.php. You want one of the tarball ones, not the Windows one. DLL is a Windows-only thing.

Comment: hmm im not sure if its possible to uninstall the php build that comes with the OSX and if it is I really don't know how ( searched for it already ) what do i need to download the openssl or the correct php?

Comment: openSSL is installed correctly. You need the correct PHP.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526085/how-do-i-upgrade-php-in-mac-os-x

Comment: I do have the right PHP but also the native one from OSX..