# Two different PHP versions running at the same time

Tags: php, macos

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526085/how-do-i-upgrade-php-in-mac-os-x) I've updated my local PHP to 7.0. This worked as expected when I browser to a file with `phpinfo()`

When I use the terminal command `php -v` I get version 5.5.26

As stated in the [FAQ](http://php-osx.liip.ch/#faq) I have to add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

to the `~/.profile` (which I had to create)

but the result is the same: `php -v` still shows the 5.5 version

Comment: you have installed php7 to /usr/local/php5 directory?

Comment: I run `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0` which does that for me

Comment: Here's the content of the /usr/local http://i.imgur.com/57Sdf5N.png The php5 is currently targeting to php5-7.0.0....

Comment: may be /usr/local/php5-7..../bin...